# Name for a ratio expressed as a decimal

Tags: terminology

Given the ratio 3:4, we can express this in different ways.

`75% - Percent
3/4 - Fraction
3:4 - Ratio`

However, I was looking for a word to describe a ratio expressed just as a simple decimal value, or a number represented as per-ten or per-dec.

`0.75 - per-unit
7.5 - per-dec`

But is there an official term for these?

Comment: See [Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)) : "A common fraction is a numeral which represents a rational number. That same number can also be represented as a **decimal**, a **percent**, or with a negative exponent. For example, $0.01, 1%$, and $10^{−2}$ all equal the fraction $\dfrac {1} {100}$."

Comment: ...and of course there is the somewhat archaic [per mille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille).